# How do I add an element to an array of structures in C?

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I'm working on a very basic C project, where I need to display a menu and calculate a bill according to what the user has chosen from the menu.
For this, I have written the following piece of code

```
struct Food_item
{
    char name[50];
    float price;
};

typedef struct Food_item food;
food french_dishes[4]={{"Champagne",450},{"Pineau",250},{"Monaco",350},{"French Cider",400}};
food order[50];

int choice = -1;
printf("Enter choice: ");
scanf("%d", &choice);
```

Now I need to add the name of the food and the price of it into my array, order.
How do I do this?
And if I decide to take multiple orders and add them to my array, order, then how do I do it?

Comment: You need a counter to keep track of the position in your `order` array. Then you can assign the elements: `order[pos] = french_dishes[selected_item];`

Comment: Would it be something like this?
 int order_pos = 0; 
printf("What would you like to order? \n");
    int selected_item;
    scanf("%d", &selected_item);
    order[order_pos]=french_dishes[selected_item];

Comment: Yes. Don't forget to check input for valid values and increment the position counter after adding an item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the scanf you can instantly save the order in the order variable you already have. And then by using a simple comparison with the menu you can calculate the final price of the order. Also in order to have multiple foods in the same order, you can use a while loop and quit whenever the order is complete.
*Don't forget to include string.h

```
printf("The Menu\n");
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    printf("Food:%s, Price: %.2f\n", french_dishes[i].name, french_dishes[i].price);
}

int end_order = 0;
int count = 0;
while(end_order==0)
{
    printf("Enter Choice(press 'q' to finish order): ");
    scanf("%s", order[count].name);
    if(*order[count].name == 'q')
    {
        end_order = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        count++;
    }
}

float final_price = 0;
printf("The Order\n");
for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
{
    printf("Food:%s\n", order[j].name);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(order[j].name,french_dishes[i].name) == 0)
        {
            final_price = final_price + french_dishes[i].price;
        }
    }
}

printf("Final Price: %.2f\n", final_price);
```

Comment: I just ran the code. It's quite self-explanatory as well so I understood how it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do I need to add cases where the person enters a wrong spelling or something of that sort as well? Because otherwise, it's not added to the final bill.

Comment: No, it's not necessary but you could if you would like to. In my implementation, the code just ignores the wrong inputs and just counts the price with the correct ones. You could add an "else" in the strcmp if statement and print that an input was wrong.

Comment: Ah yes. I just added and else too now and it kind of takes care of the other part of it. Thanks for the inputs!